# Can bit shifting ever add a 1 instead of a zero in C ? And how to avoid it?

Tags: c, bit-shift

I have a program that uses 0th bit for something and then bits 7-1 for something else. In order to check bits 7-1 I do a

```
int number = number >> 1;
```

which gives me the bits 7-1.

so for example **1111 1110** becomes **0111 1111**

I am curious if there is an edge case where that left bit will become a 1 instead of a 0? Because that would screw up my program.

If there is such case, how can I avoid it and make sure it never happens?

Comment: Is `number` unsigned?

Comment: There are cases - what is the type of number?

Comment: 16 bits only gives 65536 different cases. Do a simple loop and check them all. It's trivial. (That is, given a specific type)

Comment: If it is of type `uint8_t` then yes you can be sure it is `0` always. If it is others (`uint16_t` or so on - then make sure the bit at pos - `8` is `0`as well. To be sure that everything is alright, you can explicitly set all bits to `0` other than the LSB 8 bits.

Comment: number is an int (or a char)

Comment: @Duxa.: You are dealing with `char` then it depends if it is signed or unsigned. Check the `CHAR_MIN` if it is `0` then it is `unsigned` else it is `signed`. There are 3 types of char `signed`, `unsigned` and `plain`.

Comment: @Duxa.: It is a `char` right?

Comment: Please clarify whether the higher bits are known to be 0 or not. It should say in the question, not a comment "number is an int or a char"

Comment: To make it portable why don't you just mask it with 7 ones? If the type is unsigned, the compiler will optimize away the mask. Else it will keep it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of thing to consider.

First of all if it is `int` - and it is `unsigned` you can be sure that all the left shifted bits are `0`-'s. The 8th bit should always be `0` to make sure that the `8th` bit is `0` because that is what becomes the `7th` bit after left shifting.

For signed number the story is quite different. Suppose this is `int8_t` and right shifting this is implementation defined. But on most implementations it  would give
`1110 0000` after right shifting `1010 0000`. That's the thing.

Now you said it can be `char`. Three types of `char` - `signed` , `unsigned` and `plain`.

With unsigned the story is same as before. With signed it is also same as before. With `plain` you don't know how `char` is by default interpreted on your implementation. How to check what it is?

Check the `CHAR_MIN` to determine if it is `signed` or `unsigned` and then if it is `signed` then the result of right shift is implementation defined as mentioned by standard. So in this case it holds too what is being told about signed type.

[C11 §6.5.7 Shift operators ¶5](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p5) says: If `E1` has a `signed` type and a negative value, the *resulting value is implementation-defined.* (Jonathan Leffler pointed this out)

Answer (score 2):

After right shifting, the empty spaces are filled by leading 0s.

For example,
    11111000 >> 1 = 01111100

It will always be led by 0(s) provided it is an unsigned data type unless explicitly made to 1 using shift operators.

A tip - you can ensure that your program uses unsigned data type to always get leading zeros. You declare your variable as any of unsigned types. Example -
unsigned int, unsigned char, unsigned long, etc

Comment: This is an over-simplification.  [C11 §6.5.7 Shift operators ¶5](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p5) says: _The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. If `E1` has an unsigned type
or if `E1` has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral
part of the quotient of `E1 / (2^E2)`.  If `E1` has a signed type and a negative value, the
resulting value is implementation-defined._   (That's 2 to the power of `E2`.)  The good news is that it is defined behaviour; the bad news is that it is implementation defined.

Comment: `>>` is right-shifting

Comment: I'm very sorry for the mistake, I've edited my answer to reflect the correction. I knew that it is right shifting but I just made a mistake. I was a bit drowsy while typing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the type of the number:

- If it's unsigned, the C standard defines that you get a `0` bit shifted in. So, that's good.
- If it's signed, you *usually* get a different shift operation: The bits that are shifted in are **copies of the sign bit**. That is,

  ```
  uint8_t result = (int8_t)128 >> 1;
  ```

  will yield `result == 192`, or `11000000` in binary.

The easiest way to ensure correct operation, is to use the appropriate integer types. In your case, that would be `uint8_t`.

`char` is a very bad idea to use, because it is implementation defined whether `char` is treated as signed or unsigned. Consequently, you don't know what the result of `(char)128 >> 1` will be, unless you have checked your compiler documentation. So better avoid using `char`.

Comment: The result of the shift is also implementation-defined, if the original value was negative

Comment: @cmaster Thanks for the reply. If I have a unsigned char *pointer and then assign a signed char to it, will the number automatically become unsigned?

Comment: @M.M That is why I said "you **usually** get a different shift operation". I actually used emphasis on the word "usually". Maybe I should have used bold emphasis?

Comment: @Duxa The moment that you assign a signed value to an unsigned variable, it will be implicitly converted to unsigned. An unsigned variable can only ever hold positive values. If the value is negative, it will get `2^n` added to it, where `n` is the number of bits in the variable. So, if you do `uint8_t c = -1;`, the result will be `-1 + 2^8 = 255`. Some C programmers like to use this as a trick to set all the bits of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

> I am curious if there is an edge case where that left bit will become a 1 instead of a 0?

Yes - first this is not specified behavior attempting to use `number` before it is initialized/assigned.

```
//           v----v----- number should not be used yet
int number = number >> 1;
```

Let us change this to

```
int number = foo();
number = number >> 1;
```

---

Yes.  Post has not specified the value of bits 8, 9, 10 etc.  The following can easily shift a 1 bit into the "left" bit 7.

```
number = 0x100;
number = number >> 1;
```

It may have been implied, but it was not specified the value of upper bits were 0.  That is the risk of lack of specificity.  You may understand the goal, yet the next developer might not - and never is a long time.

---

> how can I avoid it and make sure it never happens?

**Never** happens is easy - insure upper bits are cleared with a mask - let the compiler optimize the mask out if it is not needed.  Using `unsigned` math would help if code was using 16 or more, rather than 8, bits<sup>1</sup>.  This functions as desired even if `number` was `int` or `unsigned` or any integer type.

```
number = (number & 0xFF) >> 1;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> With 16 or more bits, one of the bits could be a signed bit and best to avoid shifting that. There are addition issues if `number` was a *signed integer* encoded as *signed magnitude* or *one's complement*.